# Access target route parameters in beforeModel

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

How do I access the target route parameters in the `beforeModel` function when loading a route in Ember?

The documentation refers to `beforeModel` being the correct place to abort or redirect a transition - but without the target parameters I can't add the required logic to determine if we should redirect.

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {

    // transition doesn't seem to have the target params

  }
});
```

I was also unable to find any clear documentation on the Transition object described in the API documentation:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel

Comment: Should be transition.params['routeName'].identifier

Comment: `transition.to.params` should have them

Answer (score 5):

From the route, you can use:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    var params = this.paramsFor('post');
  }
});
```

But don't forget to declare the parameters in the corresponding controller:

```
App.PostController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: 'author title'.w()
});
```

Here, e.g, I declare `author` & `title` allowed parameters. anything else will neither be parsed nor passed to `paramsFor` caller.